# SQL How to write these complicated queries?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the schema of the database I have created and I have populated the tables with lots of data:

```
DEPARTMENT(deptnum(P), descrip, instname, deptname, state, postcode)
ACADEMIC(acnum(p), deptnum*, famname, givename, initials, title) //acnum = Academic Number
PAPER(panum(P), title) //panum = Paper Number
AUTHOR(panum*(P), acnum(P)*)
FIELD(fieldnum(P), id, title)
INTEREST(fieldnum*(P), acnum*(P), descrip)
```

Key: P = Primary Key

From this alone, how do you write a query where you find all the academics who have co-written a paper with academic number 151? The output should list the academic number, but it should not include academic number 151.

```
SELECT acnum
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

And, how do you write a query to find academics that are authors and that have only ever co-authored papers with authors from institutes in the same state as their own?

```
SELECT acnum, title, famname
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do it step by step. Find all papers written by 151. Then find others who wrote on those papers. The second is a bit more complicated, but can be though in steps, too, Use IN or EXISTS (or NOT IN / NOT EXISTS) for these queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same table in the query more than once.  Here is one way to solve the first query:

```
select p2.acnum
from ( select panum from paper where acnum = 151) p1
     join paper p2
     on p1.panum = p2.panum
where p2.acnum != 151   
/
```